# Appending FormData field with value as a boolean false causes the function to fail.

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, django, form-data

I'm trying to AJAX a simple form to a Django server where one field is the object id to be updated, and the other is a boolean field that the corresponding object should be updated to. In Javascript, I initialize a new FormData and append the form values and submit it to the server with an Ajax call. However, when the boolean form data field is set to `false`, the Ajax request fails saying that the field was not set.

The form

```
from django import forms
class UpdateHazardForm(forms.Form):
  pk = forms.IntegerField()
  fixed = forms.BooleanField()
```

relevant js code

```
var fd = new FormData();
fd.append('pk', pID)
fd.append('fixed', checked)

// Ajax changes to server
$.ajax({
  url: "/update_hazard/",
  type: 'POST',
  data: fd,
  dataType: "json",
  processData: false,
  contentType: false,
  success: function(data) {
    if (data['success']) {
      console.log("success");
    }
    else{
      console.log("not success");
    }
  }
});
```

The view function

```
@require_POST
@user_passes_test(lambda u: u.is_superuser)
def updateHazard(request):
  form = UpdateHazardForm(request.POST)
  if form.is_valid():
    pk = form.cleaned_data['pk']
    fixed = form.cleaned_data['fixed']

    hazard = get_object_or_404(Hazard, pk=pk)
    hazard.hazard_fixed=fixed
    hazard.save()

    return JsonResponse({'success': True})
  logger.debug(form.errors)
  return JsonResponse({'success': False})
```

When calling `fd.append("fixed", checked)` with checked==true, the ajax post is successful. When checked==false, it fails with error `<ul class="errorlist"><li>fixed<ul class="errorlist"><li> This field is required.</li></ul></li></ul>`

I suspect the FormData.append(name, value) function checks for a value with an if statement, which fails when the value is the boolean false. I've tried changing the "checked" value to a string with toString() but it didn't work.

Any help is appreciated. I'd prefer to keep the form field as a BooleanField to keep the view function simple.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the Boolean field to accept false, you need to set `required=False`.

```
fixed = forms.BooleanField(required=False)
```

Comment: This works. Does FormData.append("name", false) not append the data? Any idea why the failure happens?

Comment: In Django, a `BooleanField` with `required=True` is only valid if the value is True. I'm not familiar with `FormData`, so I don't know what happens in the JavaScript. You could try adding some logging to see whether the `append` call works as you expect.